# 3 Table Join SQL Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to SQL joins so bear with me, what I'm trying to do is list out student test scores by week added up per student. The query I have is,

```
SELECT
  agg.Week,
  meta.Category,
  agg.Student,
  meta.Funding,
  agg.Test_Results,
  agg.Test_Points,
  phy.Test_Results,
  phy.Test_Points
FROM Agriculture agg

INNER JOIN metadata meta
 ON meta.Student_ID = agg.Student_ID

INNER JOIN Physics phy
 ON phy.Student_ID = agg.Student_ID

WHERE agg.Week BETWEEN '1' AND '5'
```

To me this looks correct, but for some reason what is happening is the Test_Results and Test_Points are duplicating themselves over and over and I'm not sure how to fix it. What I mean by duplicating is, since the points are the same 120 each week, a student(9) will score a 95, that 95 will repeat itself for that same student over and over again. I'm not sure if I need to have a subquery added to the INNER JOINS or not.

Tables are:

metadata --> (Category, Funding, Student_ID) (One to many comparison table)

Physics --> (Test_Results, Test_Points, Student_ID) (Many to many)

Agriculture --> (Week, Student, Test_Results, Test_Points, Student_ID) (Many to Many)

Again, I'm new to joins so if you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join the table by using Student_ID. If there is more than one corresponding row in metadata for the same Student_ID from Agriculture the resultset will show duplicates.
The same goes for table Physics.

for example : You have 10 rows in table Agriculture for a Student_ID and 2 rows in metadata with the same Student_ID, you will get 20 rows if you join the tables.

You can indeed use subqueries to reduce the number of rows per Studen_ID in metadata and Physics and join on those subselects.

Comment: I created subqueries within each join and that fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use DISTINCT keyword for agg.Student.